# Viewbag in Javascript shows error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net-core, model-view-controller

I am fetching the data using API and assign it to VIEW BAG but at run time it shows me an error.

```
List<DevInfo> DevList = await RestApi.Instance.GetAllDevAsync();
var nameT = DevList.Select(a=>a.Name).ToList();
ViewBag.datasourceDevList = nameT;
```

And in the script.

```
var nameList = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("@ViewBag.datasourceDevList") %>;
```

I want to generate the dropdown list.

```
if (nameList != '') {
                var tableHtml;
                $.each(JSON.parse(nameList), function (index, value) {
                    //tableHtml += "<option value=" + value.Name + ">" + value.Name + "</option>";
                    console.log(value);
                });
                /*$("#selectTrainer").html(tableHtml);*/
                $("#selectTrainer").append(tableHtml);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `JavaScriptSerializer()` in javascript which makes the code looks complex, you can achieve generating the options via these ways:

### Solution 1: Using razor syntax

> view

```
<select id="selectTrainer">
    @if (ViewBag.datasourceDevList != null)
    {
        foreach(var option in ViewBag.datasourceDevList)
        {
            <option value="@option.Name">@option.Name</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

[Sample Solution 1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FK2oGx)

---

### Solution 2: Pass `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to `@Html.DropDownListFor`

Set your `ViewBag` with `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` element. `@Html.DropDownListFor` will generate the options based on list items.

> controller

```cs
using System.Linq;

ViewBag.datasourceDevList = DevList
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Name } )
    .ToList();
```

> view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DevID, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.datasourceDevList,
    htmlAttributes: new
    {
        @id = "selectTrainer"
    })
```

[Sample Solution 2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nfK4OV)

---

### References

[DropDownList(HtmlHelper, String, IEnumerable)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_SelectExtensions_DropDownList_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Web_Mvc_SelectListItem__)